# D3 js hexagon progress animation start point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to seek help how to set the starting point of a hexagon shape in progress animation. Based on my screenshot my issue is that my code is always start at first half of the hexagon shape.

I tried to changed my hexagon data but the issue still not in the correct starting point of the animation.

You can check my code below what's wrong. And thanks in advance.

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="animation"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
/*https://codepen.io/MarcBT/pen/wcLCe/*/
var h = (Math.sqrt(3)/2.2),
    radius = 100,
    xp = 200,
    yp = 200,
    


    hexagonData = [


    { "x": (radius/2+xp) , "y": (-radius*h+yp)},
     { "x": -radius/2+xp,  "y": -radius*h+yp},
     { "x": -radius+xp,  "y": yp},
     { "x": -radius/2+xp,  "y": radius*h+yp},
     { "x": radius/2+xp,  "y": radius*h+yp},
     { "x": radius+xp,   "y": yp},
    ];



drawHexagon = 
  d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate("cardinal-closed")
        .tension(".1")


var svgContainer = 
    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 600)
      .attr("height", 600);



var svgContainer = d3.select("#animation") //create container
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

var path = svgContainer.append('path')
 .attr('d', drawHexagon(hexagonData))
  //.attr('d',line(pointData))
  .attr('stroke', "#E2E2E1")
  .attr('stroke-width', '4')
  .attr('fill', 'none');





var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
var percent = 100;

console.log(totalLength);
path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  //.transition()
  //.duration(2000)
  //.ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset",0);



var path1 = svgContainer.append('path')
 .attr('d', drawHexagon(hexagonData))
  .attr('stroke', "green")
  .attr('stroke-width', '4')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

var totalLength = path1.node().getTotalLength();
var percent = -30;

//console.log(totalLength);
path1
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset",totalLength )
  // .attr("fill", "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", ((100 - percent)/100) *totalLength)








</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle of what you are trying to do : https://jsfiddle.net/udsnbb5m/2/

The animation is starting at the first point of your hexagon. However your points aren't the vertices of your hexagon. You can change that like that:

```
  d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed")
    .tension("0.90") // Previously 0.1
```

Okay, the animation starts properly.

Now we have to change the hexagon orientation. You can modify directly the points coordinates. (That's what I did)

```
 hexagonData = [

  { "x": xp,  "y": -radius+yp}, //5
  { "x": -radius*h+xp ,  "y": -radius/2+yp}, //4
  { "x": (-radius*h+xp) , "y": (radius/2+yp)}, //3
  { "x": xp , "y": radius+yp}, //2
  { "x": radius*h+xp ,  "y": radius/2+yp}, //1
  { "x":  radius*h+xp ,  "y":  -radius/2+yp}, //6

];
```

Note that you probably can do it with this attribute:

```
.attr('transform','rotate(-45)');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help mate